# Elastic search - return documents which have strings other than a specific string

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5

I want to return those documents which have any other values in infoList other than the one's starting from "cake". Eg: This is the complete data:

```
  {   "brand" : "A",
      "productType" : "food",
      "infoList" : [
        "pizza-34","cake-qaw-34"
      ]},
   {
      "brand" : "B",
      "productType" : "food",
      "infoList" : [
        "pasta-3"
      ]},
   {
      "brand" : "c",
      "productType" : "food",
      "infoList" : [
        "cake-233"
      ]}
```

After running the elastic search query, I should get these data only because they have other values (pizza-34, pasta-3) which do not begin with "cake". If there is any document that has only cake then it should not be returned.

```
{   "brand" : "A",
      "productType" : "food",
      "infoList" : [
        "pizza-34","cake-qaw-34"
      ]},
   {
      "brand" : "B",
      "productType" : "food",
      "infoList" : [
        "pasta-3"
      ]},
```

Answer (score 1):

In Elasticsearch, there is no dedicated array data type. Any field can contain zero or more values by default, however, all values in the array must be of the same data type more information [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/array.html). Due to this there is no way to distinguish between elements in Array data type. So if you run this query:

**Query:**

```
GET myindex2/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "prefix": {
            "infoList": "cake"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The result will look like this:

**Result:**

```
"_source" : {
          "brand" : "B",
          "productType" : "food",
          "infoList" : [
            "pasta-3"
          ]
}
```

As you can see you will only get the document that doesn't have cake and document with "pizza-34","cake-qaw-34" will not returned as Elastic see the whole array as a single string. If you want to get results that you want you will need to query from Elasticsearch and then filter the result.

Comment: can you show how to get that result ? Also, all the data in my array infoList is of string datatype

Comment: There is not an easy way to do the query you want in Elasticsearch you will need to change your mapping to support better your requirements or retrieve data from ES and filter the result you like in your backend.